# If $f'(x)\to b$ when $x\to \infty$, prove $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=b$ for any $h>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ and differentiable in $(0,\infty)$.

I am trying to show that for any $h>0$, $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=b$, when $f\to b$ and $x\to \infty$.
I've been trying to solve this, but got stuck, I believe that by the definition of derivative it should be easy to get the result, but not quite sure how to proceed.

Comment: Apply MVT to $f(x+h)-f(x)$.

Comment: Hint: Try integrating $f’(x)$ over a fixed interval of length $h$

Comment: Since we have been studying the MVT, I believe it is right to proceed with it, but not sure how to apply it though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First fix $h>0$. For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $M>0$ such that $x>M$ implies $|f'(x)-b|<\varepsilon$. On the other hand, for any $x>M$, $f$ is differentiable on the interval $[x,x+h]$, so there exists $c_x\in (x,x+h)$ such that

$$f'(c_x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

Now for any $x>M$, we have

$$\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-b\right|= \left|f'(c_x)-b\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that ${f(x+h)-f(x) \over h} = f'(x+t_x h)$ for some $t_x \in (0,1)$.

Show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x+t_x h) = b$.